# image segmentation using spatial(location) feature

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, feature-extraction

I am using Mean Shift Clustering algorithm for the image segmentation. I have to define a feature vector. How can I define a feature that containes location(spatial) information of each pixel in the image. I defined color and depth features already but I have no idea for the location feature. Any idea or suggestions?

Comment: Voting to close as this question does not belong on Stack Overflow... perhaps Signal Processing SE: http://dsp.stackexchange.com (btw, I have no idea how this question got 2 votes and 2 favourites).